# Single storage account as checkpoint store for app services that use event hubs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-eventhub

Is it ok to have 1 single storage account as checkpoint store referenced by multiple app services that use event hubs?
Or is it better to have 1 storage account per app service, as it is recommended for azure functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#optimize-storage-performance)?

Comment: Are we talking about one event hub or multiple event hubs?

Comment: Are you planning on using different containers for each in the account?   Is your intent for them to work independently or coordinate to share partitions?

Comment: @PeterBons 1 event hub namespace with multiple event hubs.

Comment: @JesseSquire eventually if the service needs to scale and another instance of it is created, it will use a different partition but be in the same consumer group.

Comment: Processors only coordinate when they use the same consumer group and storage container; if your "multiple app services" intend to share work, they need the same storage account.   If not, Peter's answer is spot-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons it is recommended to use seperate, dedicated storage account per event hub. As the docs say:

> It's important to use separate storage accounts since Event Hubs triggered functions can potentially have a high volume of storage transactions due to checkpointing.

So it is the checkpointing that can cause high volume of transactions. That is why you should seperate the storage accounts used by the webapp/function/whatever from the ones used by each event hub.

There are virtually no extra costs attached to having multiple storage accounts if that is your reasoning for this question.

Comment: Thanks, I expected that much, just needed confirmation :)